# What spells can the Inscribe Magic Tattoo feat be used for?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, feats, sorcerer

The item creation feat [Inscribe Magic Tattoo](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/item-creation-feats/inscribe-magical-tattoo-item-creation/) has a short list of sample magic tattoos, but there is no list given for what you can and can't tattoo. Does this use the Sorcerer/Wizard spell list in its entirety? Or is it only the tattoos listed on the [Wondrous Items](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/) page?

If it uses the Sorcerer/Wizard list, for example, how do you figure out the pricing of tattooing [Burning Hands](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/b/burning-hands/) on your hand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Potentially any spell can be tattooed

First, for your specific case of having Burning Hands tattooed on your hand, note the existing [Spell Tattoo](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/r-z/tattoo-spell) which works in a similar way to a scroll and is just a one time use. The price listed for this tattoo is:

> A spell tattoo has a market price four times as much as an equivalent scroll.

So for a normal Burning Hands of caster level 1, the market price would be 25x4=100 gp but creating it would cost half this price (50 gp) since Inscribe Magical Tattoo follows the rules for magic item creation.

If you don't want to have this burning hands spell to be single use you can also use the option of creating a new tattoo:

> New magical tattoos can be researched and designed using the guidelines for pricing new magic items. Magical tattoos are treated as slotless magical items for pricing purposes.

By consulting the [section on pricing magic items](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-item-creation/?/#Magic_Item_Gold_Piece_Values), you can figure out how much it would cost to create a tattoo of a spell with more ways to be activated (remembering that as tattoos count as slotless items they would always cost double).

Since no limitation is placed on which spells can be inscribed this way, any spell can potentially be tattooed with DM approval.